# MongoDB: Existence of a nested key

Tags: mongodb

I'm using some nested documents...  how would it be possible to check 
existence of just a key?

Ie.. if I wanted to return any record that had a nested key "work", where the parent key is dynamic.

Here is a record that should be returned:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"), 
    "customer_name" : "test user", 
    "123456" : { 
            "home" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 
            "work" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 

    }, 
    "321456" : { 
            "home" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 
            "work" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 

    }, 
    "789654" : { 
            "home" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 
            "work" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 

    }, 
    "createad" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09" 
}
```

Here is a record that should not be returned:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"), 
    "customer_name" : "test user", 
    "123456" : { 
            "home" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 
    }, 
    "321456" : { 
            "home" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 
            "home1" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 

    }, 
    "321543" : { 
            "home" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 
            "home1" : { 
                    "id" : "1536734296", 
                    "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09", 
            } 

    }, 
    "createad" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09" 
}
```

My guess it will be something like:
    db.find({"*.work":{"$exists":true}})
any Idea?

Comment: `*.work` will not work. You need the parent key.

Comment: I know, this is why I posted the question...

Comment: If you can't fix the schema as chridam correctly suggests, then you'll need to use [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) and live with the poor performance.

Answer (score 4):

With MongoDb version >= 3.6 you can leverage the operator [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) in your query and use the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator to convert the dynamic object to an array, filter the array for the work value field using [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) as the conditional operator.

The following example demonstrates this approach:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $gt: [
            {
                $size: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: { $objectToArray: '$$ROOT' },
                        cond: { 
                            $ifNull: ['$$this.v.work', false]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            0
        ]
    }
})
```

---

<del>It is not good practice to have values as keys and currently (and probably in the future, too) it's not possible to query MongoDB collections with wildcards in fieldnames.</del>

For an alternative schema design easy to query, I would suggest a schema redesign that follows this model:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55128d6315f3df650f2038cf"),
"customer_name" : "test user",
"createad" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09",
"data" : [ 
    {
        "key" : "123456",
        "home" : {
            "id" : "1536734296",
            "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09"
        },
        "work" : {
            "id" : "1536734296",
            "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "key" : "321456",
        "home" : {
            "id" : "1536734296",
            "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09"
        },
        "work" : {
            "id" : "1536734296",
            "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "key" : "789654",
        "home" : {
            "id" : "1536734296",
            "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09"
        },
        "work" : {
            "id" : "1536734296",
            "last" : "2011-04-14 16:44:09"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Which you can query as follows

```
db.collection.find({ "data.work" : { $exists : true, $ne : null } })
```

to check for the existence of the `work` field in the `data` array.

Comment: I have a different problem that prevents me from this redesign in the data schema

Answer (score 0):

if your parent key is different you will have to get all the data to your application an loop through it.
because of the way mongodb store data you can't do query like that if you have different parent key. you will have to get all the document to your Application and loop thru it and check it yourself.

If you have a lot of data and you don't want to get all the data to your application i recommend you to arrange your data differently so you will have a way to query your data faster