# Use a wildcard for extract just one type of data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a translations structure like the following:

```
{
    "hello": {
        "es": "Hola",
        "en": "Hello"
    },
    "hello2": {
        "es": "Hola2"
    }
}
```

I want to extract for example the "es" language only. I know I can get all and extract the data with javascript but i want to be if its possible with mongo.

I tried:

`let exists = await col.find({}).project({ $regex: { '*.en': 1 } }).toArray()`

But dosen't works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252670/mongodb-existence-of-a-nested-key See this.